# Can trehalose be organic? How is it listed as an ingredient?

Tags: additives, organic

I saw a worrying [report](https://arstechnica.com/science/2018/01/the-curious-case-of-a-boring-sugar-that-may-have-unleashed-a-savage-plague/) of an [article in *Nature*](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature25178.epdf?referrer_access_token=lOtthKfRzDJerYm0VOGWvtRgN0jAjWel9jnR3ZoTv0NVgVqHgLS8rr1n-LKGk-6CE26R3_B_GxzwACSgQFbe7zsywPbBV3VK9D6fCz-JMs2cJba4pa2-DdE5W9Q9G3GXX3256Lho0DAQFbYmGQJGWoV_TEQDQkfyTGA7Js0wIdCe6ggSzGUX0M6Q99zEbqZ4V0AKLfLnon4RkeeoSogJvHnX7x9ifdNQWEUm2ISXBwfOp73AZAtcTax_Oy8VsaiUL5Gys-rk6ntCA-qVu8FHMRSM4Vk3PWWnOVhbaZ_Xe5Q%3D&tracking_referrer=arstechnica.com), no less, questioning whether the sugar substitute [trehalose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trehalose) could be a cause of the recent rise in *Clostridium difficile* infections.

As a precaution, I'd like to know how to avoid trehalose. Our family here in the UK eats mostly organic food. **Is it possible for trehalose to be present in an organic certified product?** I note that some suppliers [purport to sell](https://www.alibaba.com/showroom/organic-trehalose.html) "organic trehalose".

If a food contains trehalose, **how does it appear in the ingredient list?** (Especially in the UK.) Will it be called "trehalose", or some E-number, or something else?

Thanks!

Comment: Beware of supermarket sushi (as in, not prepared fresh to order) - trehalose is commonly used to keep the rice from staling.

Comment: Looking online at the ingredients in UK supermarket sushi, I see "sugar" added to the rice, but no mention of trehalose. I wonder if they can just call it sugar? It is a sugar, after all. Thanks! Plus, I see that trehalose does not have an E-number, unless it's called something different there.

Comment: Sugar, Modified Anystarch, Spices and Flavourings - while they are not necessarily bad for you, they are bad for ingredient disclosure.

Comment: I wrote to the UK Food Safety Agency with this question. Their computer says I should see an answer in a few days. Or 20 days if it's a hard question.

Comment: Some sushi recipes (and fresh sushi) use ordinary sugar.